# How to verify domain ownership for Google Maps Api using CPanel?

Tags: dns, cpanel

I am [having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442448/google-maps-api-for-both-localhost-production-server-as-of-april-2019) tryign to configure a Google Maps API key.

I could be wrong, but it looks like I have to associate a domain with the API key, using  https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification

However, I can't see how to do so, using CPanel.

Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: To my knowledge CPanel can't make changes to the DNS of your domain. Usually your hosting has a separate control panel for making changes to DNS or you can send a support ticket so they make the changes for you.

Comment: Lolx !  I didn't think of asking support. Feel free to post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge CPanel can't make changes to the DNS of your domain. Usually your hosting has a separate control panel for making changes to DNS or you can send a support ticket so they make the changes for you.